# Where are Apple's default desktop images stored?

Tags: macos, desktop

When I go to System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver, I see many images in folders such as "Desktop Pictures", "Nature", "Plants", etc. Where are these images located?

I want to use them in an application such as SpaceSuit to set them as background images for different spaces.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They're in `/Library/Desktop Pictures/`

Answer (score 15):

As of macOS 12:

- Desktop JPEG wallpaper are located in `/Library/Desktop Pictures`
- Pre-installed dynamic wallpapers (HEIF) are located in `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures`
- Any dynamic wallpapers downloaded by the user (from the "Desktop & Screen Saver" preferences) are located in `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/com.apple.mobileAssetDesktop`

Answer (score 9):

As of macOS 10.15 (Catalina) the location is `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures`. I'm unsure what version the location switched.

Answer (score 2):

Further update for macOS 14.

`/Library/Desktop Pictures` no longer exists.

These are still valid:

`/System/Library/Desktop Pictures`
`/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/com.apple.mobileAssetDesktop`

The new screen saver/desktop videos are kept in subdirectories for various resolutions and HDR/SDR here:

`/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.idleassetsd/Customer/`

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: up to macOS 12, you can get macOS to show you the folder by opening `System Preferences > Desktop and screensaver` then double clicking the folder name on the left where it says `Apple > Wallpapers`. It will open the folder on Finder (which is on `/System/Library/Desktop Pictures`).

I couldn't find a way to get the folder from System Settings on macOS 13 Ventura.

Answer (score 0):

#### 2024 (macOS Sonoma)

The **moving wallpapers** are located under:

`/Library/Application Support/com.apple.idleassetsd/Customer`

---

The **normal wallpapers** are located under:

`/System/Library/Desktop Pictures`

Make sure you can see hidden folders. Try <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (command+shift+dot) to toggle visibility of hidden folders.