# Where are the default (system) wallpaper folders located on OS X?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are Apple's default desktop images stored?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8319/where-are-apples-default-desktop-images-stored)

Does anybody know where the folders containing the default (i.e. system) wallpapers are located on OS X Lion? (it may not have changed from previous versions of OS X, so please also tell me if you know where they are on a previous version of OS X). Thanks!

[EDIT:] Indeed, a dupe. What threw me off was that I was looking for "Wallpaper", not "Desktop Pictures". Maybe add a tag synonym [wallpaper] for [desktop], to aid searching people who make the same mistake.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Its on:

`/Library/Desktop Pictures/`

Notice though this is the **system library**, not the user library, so its right on the root of the drive and not inside your user folder.

Its hidden by default. Go to terminal and type `open /Library` to open it.

Hope it helps!

---

**Edit:** On Finder, you can hit <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and paste the path to go to the folder. (thanks Sjoerd)

Comment: I used CMD+Shift+G to paste the path there... also works fine. Thanks! I was aware of the now-hidden-by-default Library folders, I must have been looking right past it a couple of times... :)

Comment: Haha right. Cmd+Shift+G! Sorry, I'm a Terminal kind of person :P Your welcome! Glad it helped.

Comment: If you cannot remember arcane incantations like CMD-Shift-G, you can instead look in the Finder's **Go** menu.